# Failed to find 'Power Electronics/Full-Bridge Converter' in library 'powerlib'?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Im trying to run a simulation (done in matlab 2020a I guess) but when running it , it gives the next error

```
Failed to find 'Power Electronics/Full-Bridge Converter' in library 'powerlib' referenced by Full-Bridge Converter'
```

But in my install it already has the toolboxes installed

```
SimElectronics                                        Version 2.5        (R2014a)
SimMechanics                                          Version 4.4        (R2014a)
SimPowerSystems                                       Version 6.1        (R2014a)
Simscape                                              Version 3.11       (R2014a)
```

I have been told these are necessary,but then what? the needed toolboxes are supposed to be installed. What more is needed?

PD
Some friend told me the simpowersystems were merged alongside the simelectronics, into SimscapePowerSystems, so guessing the model is writen in that, whats the lower version with comes with these toolbox?, 2017?, 2016?

Comment: The Full-Bridge Converter is now part of Simscape Electrical, It used to be part of  SimPowerSystems.  Simscape Electrical also includes what used to be SimElectronics.

Comment: Downgrading models is always problematic particularly something as old as R2014a. I'd search your library browser to see if you can find the block.